# How to set team capacity in Jira

Tags: jira, scrum, kanban, scrumboard

Is there a functionality to predict team capacity for given sprint (excluding leave plans or public holiday) in Jira? Pretty much similar to Visual Studio Online Team Capacity feature. https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/work-in-sprints-vs

Comment: At VS, what is the measure of the capacity? effectively worked hours per day? snakes per plane?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. I'm asking how do we calculate the capacity of the team by entering public holiday, leave etc just like visual studio online.

Comment: @Koshinae the visual studio default is hours per day accumulated for all days in the sprint. Team members can set days off an TFS can track team days off as well. Each team member can be assigned an activity type allowing you to see capacity by activity as well.

It's considered a bad practice for scrum/agile teams.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're looking for [Jira Confluence Team Calendar](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/team-calendars)s, an additional module that can be activated on your Jira instance which will allow you to track Team availability.

[image]

I do not think it actually matches the TFS capacity module, but then again, the by activity capacity is broken by design (it assumes team members are involved in only one type of activity). And the capacity in hours always causes teams to be over confident.

If you have a 2 week sprint, quickly adding up the off-days in the team should be enough to formulate the plan for the sprint during the Sprint Planning Meeting.

If your team availability is harder to calculate than that, you have other issues int the team ;).